# Hibernate criteria.setFirstResult in hql?

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria

I want to imeplemnt this hibernate code in hql. assume that criteria restrictions have already been added. What is the way of setting first result and max result in hql (for some result)?

```
  int firstResult = (page - 1) * pgSize;
  criteria.setFirstResult(firstResult);
  criteria.setMaxResults(pgSize);
```

Comment: The identical way - `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("Your Query").setFirstResult(firstResult).setMaxResults(pgSize);` Or use `EntityManager` with the same methods, if you happen to use it.

Comment: thanks. I think it'll work.